# Upgrading TFS from 2012 and dealing with the Xaml build server

Tags: tfs, build-server

We are currently running TFS 2012 with a 2012 build server and would like to upgrade to the latest TFS.

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements?view=vsts), 2012 Xaml builds are only compatible up to TFS 2013.  However this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-relnotes) says that TFS 2018 update is compatable with Xaml builds.  Would I be able to use my existing build server?  Would I need to upgrade the current xaml builds that we use?

Answer (score 3):

This can be confusing, so let me break it down a bit:

In general, a given version of TFS supports XAML build controllers for:

- The current version
- The previous version
- TFS 2010 (for legacy reasons -- build servers running Windows XP, for example).

So, for TFS 2012, you can expect it supports TFS 2010 and TFS 2012 XAML build controllers.

TFS 2013 should support 2010, 2012, 2013.

TFS 2015 **drops support for 2012 XAML controllers**. This is also the last version for which a XAML build controller was released. TFS 2017 and TFS 2018 do not include a new version of the XAML build controller.

Therefore, TFS 2017 supports XAML build controllers for:

- TFS 2010
- TFS 2015

TFS 2018 RTM and Update 1 **did not include XAML build support**. XAML build support was reintroduced in Update 2, with the same compatbility matrix as TFS 2017.

XAML build is long-deprecated at this point. As soon as you are stabilized on a version that supports the new build system, you need to start migrating off of XAML build.

Comment: Does this mean that I can upgrade TFS to 2018, use the existing XAML builds, and then update?

Comment: Yes, with caveats: 1) You have to upgrade to TFS 2018 Update 2. 2) You have to update your build controller to the version that shipped with TFS 2015, which means you'll need to upgrade your XAML build process templates. It's unlikely to be a pain-free process.

Comment: @Nick You're not going to love this answer, but no, not really. If you've customized your process templates, you're likely going to have to redo the customizations, **then** ultimately throw it all away to migrate to the new build system. If you're using the default build process templates, it should be as easy as switching your existing XAML builds over to the latest one -- I think `TfvcTemplate.12.xaml` was the last out-of-the-box revision, which shipped with TFS 2013.

Comment: There's also an off chance that the TFS 2012 build process templates will still work with TFS 2015+, against a TFS 2015 XAML controller -- I haven't gone through that process in a few years, so the best bet will be to do a test migration and figure out what does and doesn't still work.